# Calculate possible password combinations in 8 character password?

Tags: passwords

Can anyone help me to understand how to calculate the number of possible password combinations when they are required to be 8 characters long? If you include uppercase, lowercase and digits.

So i thought it would be as follows:
26 lowercase + 26 uppercase + 10 digits (0-9) = 62
so 62^8 possible combinations? But from online it looks unclear and im unsure if i am missing a step or if i am correct.

Answer (score 0):

For your simple case of only using the standard 26 letters with/without capitalization and the 10 numbers, then yes, there are (26 * 2 + 10)^8 possible combinations (218340105584896 combinations).
Many people have decided to discuss password security in terms of entropy, with more entropy meaning a more secure password. Entropy (in this context) is defined by the formula:
`entropy = log2( (available characters) ** (length of password)`
The entropy of this possible 8 character password with 62 possible character is 47.633570483095. Adding two more characters jumps the entropy up to 59.54.
There are 100 printable characters (defined with the python module `string`), which can jump the entropy on an 8 character (from 47.63) to 53.15.  In general, increasing the length of your passwords greatly improves their security. (Also, avoiding dictionary words is a good idea since most password attacks walk through lists of known passwords and then dictionary word combinations.)

Here is a python function I wrote as part of my password generator which will calculate entropy:

```
def entropy(
    password: Annotated[str, "password to check"]
) -> Annotated[float, "return float representing entropy"]:
    """Calculate the entropy for a password, return the value as a float."""
    from string import printable
    from math import log2

    return log2((len(printable) - 5) ** len(password))
```

I then use this entropy to describe the safety of the password choices that are generated. Here is an example of the output:

```
1447~pebble&Flewan  118 bits of entropy
 Character Walking: 1.7e+14 centuries to bruteforce on 25 AMD Radeon GPUs
8915%Krios_Papyrus  118 bits of entropy
 Character Walking: 2e+14 centuries to bruteforce on 25 AMD Radeon GPUs
Scutret~Untimed&5028    131 bits of entropy
 Character Walking: 1.3e+18 centuries to bruteforce on 25 AMD Radeon GPUs
```

Notice that I use the entropy to tell me how many years (or centuries) it would take a dedicated GPU cluster to crack the password walking through the possible choices.

Here is a similar question posted over in the math area:
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/739874/how-many-possible-combinations-in-8-character-password